# Python regex group parsing of input with multiple groups that may or may not be present

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, data-cleaning

If I have a file of inputs with loose form (when I say loose form I mean that not all lines contain all information as is explained later on):

```
23 1990-10-10 Clark Kent
```

And I want to define a group for age, date, and name, how do I go about extracting these into a named groupdict() such as

```
{ age: 23, date: '1990-10-10', name: 'Clark Kent' }
```

If fields age or date are missing, such as:

```
1990-10-10 Clark Kent
```

or

```
23 Clark Kent
```

The groups should still be able to be parsed and return None for the fields that it couldn't find.

```
{ age: 23, date: None, name: 'Clark Kent' }
```

Now:

```
re.match(r'(?P<age>[0-9]+)?\s*(?P<birthday>\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d)?\s*(?P<name>(\w|\s)+)',
 "23 1990-10-10 Clark Kent")
```

Returns the desired output.

When however the testing string is:

```
"1990-10-10 Clark Kent"
```

Then the age parameter grabs the initial 199 greedily and the birthday fails to be parsed correctly.

How would you go about parsing this file to permissively grab whatever fields can be grabbed?

Comment: Can you share HTML source and how you get `23 1990-10-10 Clark Kent` from it? Usually regex is not what you need to get data from webpage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the groups optional including the space separator, by joining them inside a non-capturing group, like

```
(?:(?P<age>[0-9]+) +)?(?:(?P<birthday>\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d) +)?(?P<name>[\w ]+)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/a41VTh/1

I have used literal spaces as separator to avoid line overlapping matches due to the fact that `\s` also matches newlines. You might want to add a tab `[ \t]` if that is needed.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Do you mind explaining how making the groups non-capturing groups makes this work?

Comment: @Master_Yoda I did not make the groups non-capturing (as they are still present and not changed from your original pattern), they are just surrounded with the non-capturing groups to keep them together with the separating spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You **have not** asked for this. However, I think it worth mentioning that **pyparsing** is often an easier alternative to regex that should be considered.

I begin by defining a grammar for your inputs.

- Dates are a series of numbers separated by hyphens.
- Ages are numbers at most two digits long.
- Names are alphabetic characters with interspersed blanks. (This should probably be improved with hyphens and apostrophes.)

I make a complete `whole` by saying that an optional age is (implicitly) followed by an optional date followed by a required name.

I think you would agree that this is fairly simple compared to a regex.

The things like `('age')`, for example, arrange to save items that are parsed out as results for retrieval in code.

```
>>> import pyparsing as p
>>> date = p.Word(p.nums+'-')
>>> age = p.Word(p.nums, max=2)
>>> name = p.Word(p.alphas+' ')
>>> whole = p.Optional(age)('age') + p.Optional(date)('date') + name('name')
```

Now I can exercise this grammar against your strings. As is indicated, `result` acts like a `dict`. I contains any items that were parsed from each string.

```
>>> result = whole.parseString('23 1990-10-10 Clark Kent')
>>> [result[_] for _ in ['age', 'date', 'name'] if _ in result]
['23', '1990-10-10', 'Clark Kent']
>>> result = whole.parseString('1990-10-10 Clark Kent')
>>> [result[_] for _ in ['age', 'date', 'name'] if _ in result]
['1990-10-10', 'Clark Kent']
>>> result = whole.parseString('23 Clark Kent')
>>> [result[_] for _ in ['age', 'date', 'name'] if _ in result]
['23', 'Clark Kent']
```

Comment: You can also see which names parsed as a nested structure using `print(result.dump())`

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I use that nowadays, probably on the basis of advice you've offered elsewhere. In this answer I wanted to emphasise how neatly pyparsing results can be made.